# Garbage collection of singletons in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

When I use a singleton in a servlet and the singleton class creates an ArrayList such as:

```
private static ArrayList<SessionData> mSessionData = new ArrayList<>();
```

when the servlet is eventually terminated and garbage collected after a period of time when no more requests are received, does the singleton cause a memory leak by retaining a reference to the ArrayList shown above? Normally, things are garbaged collected when they have no root references. But singletons have no root reference as they can be referenced anywhere throughout the servlet and are only instantiated when they are first called upon.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html

Comment: Note: if you have a singleton in a servlet, then that singleton will be accessed by multiple threads concurrently, and you should properly synchronize access to your data structures (proper synchronization as defined in the Java Memory Model, which is chapter 17 of the JLS). Your `mSessionData` is a risk - unless you only access it from methods that `synchronize` on the same monitor, you can end up with data corruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singleton will remain in the memory so it will not be garbage collected. That's by the design. You list will also remain in memory while the application is running as part of the singleton.

That's not a memory leak though!

> a memory leak occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages
>   memory allocations

A memory leak is when there are multiple objects accumulating which don't get garbage collected and they fill up the memory. In your case you have just one object by design (the singleton) and it won't take more memory than what it actually uses - so it's not a leak and it allocates the memory properly.

How you manage the memory using the array list depends on you. If you fill it with objects and never clear them it might cause a memory leak but that won't be related to the singleton. So if you keep SessionData objects in your array list which reference sessions that are already closed/inactive you should clear them from the list (and let java eventually GC them). Usually in web programming the session management can be handled for you by the framework you use.

In servlet container each servlet is in separate context. That's main thing for the security for a web application. So if you use that singleton in different applications/servlets they will each get their own instance. That encapsulation is very important for several reason. Imagine you create a singleton class and a malicious software is installed in the same servlet container. If they instance the same class and they get your instance they will be able to read your data. And that shouldn't happen. So each servlet instance will have it's own instance of the singleton and when the servlet is gone the singleton instance will go away with it.

For an example you can check here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

How tomcat class loading works. I believe most servlet containers work like that. Singleton can have two instances if different class loaders load it. So in tomcat's case:

```
  Bootstrap
      |
   System
      |
   Common
   /     \
Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
```

Your Singleton will be loaded for each webapp. Actually all web apps have their own class loader. If you use a singleton class from the bootstrap class loader (for example java.lang.runtime or something like that) then it will be shared. But the servlet container will probably restrict you from using these anyway.

Another similar problem which is solved by that separation of class loaders is the static values. If you have a class with a public static value in your servlet a different servlet cannot modify your static value because they work in separated class loaders.

Comment: But when a container terminates a servlet and if the singleton still sticks around, is that same singleton still used the next time the container goes to create a new servlet? Or does a new singleton get created? This isn't clear because it isn't clear whether each servlet instance operates in a separate process. If that were the case, a new singleton would be created, thus creating an accumulation of singletons and hence the memory leak.

Comment: I changed my answer a bit

Comment: You wrote: "So if you use that singleton in different applications/servlets they will each get their own instance." How do you know that? I can create a Java app that instantiates two class instances of some class and both reference the same singleton. So what's to say that the container doesn't do the same when it creates multiple servlets?

Comment: Which servlet container are you using?

Comment: Servlet spec 3.1 running under Jetty 9 using Java 8.